# Shortest possible way to get "id" from JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I have a org.json.JSONObject like below:

```
{"entries":
   [{"entry":{"createdAt":"2020-06-25T18:10:22.571+0000","isFolder":false,"isFile":true,"createdByUser":{"displayName":"Administrator","id":"admin"},"modifiedAt":"2020-09-28T15:42:50.253+0000","modifiedByUser":{"displayName":"Administrator","id":"admin"},"name":"1000024_Resume 1-K_User1 (2020-1601307769393).doc","id":"a9aa23ac-3cca-4fd7-9f82-ec31c2b969f0","nodeType":"hr:HR_Type","content":{"sizeInBytes":48128,"mimeTypeName":"Microsoft Word","mimeType":"application/msword","encoding":"UTF-8"},"parentId":"7db2d13f-db92-4401-aff1-cecddd78db45"}},
   {"entry":{"createdAt":"2020-06-25T18:10:23.014+0000","isFolder":false,"isFile":true,"createdByUser":{"displayName":"Administrator","id":"admin"},"modifiedAt":"2020-07-10T20:40:33.123+0000","modifiedByUser":{"displayName":"Sarah Campbell","id":"SACAMPBELL"},"name":"Test.DOC","id":"29cfee8d-5614-4c81-9bfa-581334cc39e9","nodeType":"hr:Test_Type","content":{"sizeInBytes":35328,"mimeTypeName":"Microsoft Word","mimeType":"application/msword","encoding":"UTF-8"},"parentId":"79d3b939-b7e9-4bed-be67-428eb5da0f16"}},
   {"entry":{"createdAt":"2020-07-10T15:06:06.252+0000","isFolder":false,"isFile":true,"createdByUser":{"displayName":"Test Display","id":"CN158931"},"modifiedAt":"2020-09-28T15:39:40.349+0000","modifiedByUser":{"displayName":"Administrator","id":"admin"},"name":"1000536_Test Display September 2014.doc","id":"9eea5068-48dc-4e1f-9a19-e7d9749ba3db","nodeType":"hr:Test_Type","content":{"sizeInBytes":58243,"mimeTypeName":"Microsoft Word","mimeType":"application/msword","encoding":"UTF-8"},"parentId":"79d3b939-b7e9-4bed-be67-428eb5da0f16"}},
   {"entry":{"createdAt":"2020-07-10T21:09:50.889+0000","isFolder":false,"isFile":true,"createdByUser":{"displayName":"Test Display-Name","id":"CN103107"},"modifiedAt":"2020-07-10T21:11:26.528+0000","modifiedByUser":{"displayName":"Some-CGT12","id":"CN103107"},"name":"Test Display123.jpg","id":"df7c76a1-67b9-4673-8fb7-1a2470d42c1d","nodeType":"hr:Test_Type","content":{"sizeInBytes":237560,"mimeTypeName":"JPEG Image","mimeType":"image/jpeg","encoding":"UTF-8"},"parentId":"7db2d13f-db92-4401-aff1-cecddd78db45"}},
   {"entry":{"createdAt":"2020-07-10T21:09:51.706+0000","isFolder":false,"isFile":true,"createdByUser":{"displayName":"Test Display-Name","id":"CN103107"},"modifiedAt":"2020-07-10T21:09:51.706+0000","modifiedByUser":{"displayName":"Some-TEst2","id":"CN103107"},"name":"batman.jpg","id":"88ac8b96-5965-4668-9e94-2b2e3509e0f8","nodeType":"hr:HR_Type","content":{"sizeInBytes":5588,"mimeTypeName":"JPEG Image","mimeType":"image/jpeg","encoding":"UTF-8"},"parentId":"79d3b939-b7e9-4bed-be67-428eb5da0f16"}}]
   ,"pagination":{"maxItems":100,"hasMoreItems":false,"totalItems":5,"count":5,"skipCount":0}}
```

How do I get the value for all "id"s (`a9aa23ac-3cca-4fd7-9f82-ec31c2b969f0`, `29cfee8d-5614-4c81-9bfa-581334cc39e9`, `9eea5068-48dc-4e1f-9a19-e7d9749ba3db`, `df7c76a1-67b9-4673-8fb7-1a2470d42c1d`, `88ac8b96-5965-4668-9e94-2b2e3509e0f8`)  from above without using for loops. That means I dont want to iterate through all the objects and then get "id" value.

I am trying to do something like:

```
org.json.JSONObject myJSONObject = new org.json.JSONObject(response.getBody()).getJSONObject("entries").getJSONObject("entry").getString("id");
```

If possible, I am looking for one-liner using Java 1.6/1.7/1.8 for above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a single liner solution, but it becomes very easy using `JSON PATH` library
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path

```
Configuration cf = Configuration.builder().options(Option.SUPPRESS_EXCEPTIONS).build();
DocumentContext ctx = JsonPath.using(cf).parse(jsonStr);
List<String> ids = ctx.read("$.entries[*].entry.id");
```

Comment: Awesome !! ..  I wish we could have something similar in Standard Java Library. So many libraries to deal with JSONObjects so as SO is flooded with similar questions.  Thanks so much for your time and effort @Ratish.